# Ocelot setup to redirect user on a react application

Tags: redirect, iis, server, ocelot, server-configuration

We are doing some server set up.
We are using a Api gateway(Ocelot) installed on the server Y which will connect to Apis hosted on server X.
Server X also has a react application.
Server Y is accessible over Internet where as server X is accessible from server Y.
Now the Apis are working perfectly but the react application is not opening through the ocelot ( server Y).
So question is will ocelot open react application?

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying the ocelot api gateway in a DMZ and the react-app and web services, database behind the firewall and allow only specific access via browser, mobile.

is this a pwa site, then you should be careful about using ocelot for something that is not intended for. ocelot is an api gateway tool/technology and not unlike nginx that can perform this additional activity of routing the calls to web application and web services.

please check the documentation of ocelot api gateway, if it allows for web application routing as well.

Comment: Gateway is in DMZ but the web application is not behind the firewall.
Gateway is on one server and web application is on another server and firewall is disabled on both the servers.
Connectivity is there between these two servers.
We are able to reach till web application but I guess it is not returning the desired output and ocelot failure error in the event viewer.